# Concept behind .length in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The size of the array prints 4, why is it not 5 ? Is this something to do with the .push method ?

```
var box = [];
box.push({
  "cat": "kitten"
})
box.push("a string");
box.push(111); //comment 
var boxObject = {}
boxObject["material"] = "cardboard";
boxObject["dimensions"] = {
  "height": 2,
  "width": 60
} //comment
boxObject["array property Inside object"] = ["U2", "REM"];
boxObject.area = function() {
  return box.dimensions.height * box.dimensions.width;
}

box.push(boxObject); //comment
box["myitem"] = "cat";
console.log(`size of array is ${box.length}`);
for (var item in box) {
  console.log(`type:${typeof box[item]} and value:`,
    box[item]);
}
console.log(`size of array is ${box.length}`);
for (var item2 in box) { // prints 5 properties
  console.log(item2)
}
```

I expected .length to give 5 but it returns 4. Is this something to do  with the .push method ?

Comment: This is very unclear question.

Comment: What happens when I do box["myitem"] = "cat"
The last iteration prints 5 items(4 indices and 1 property name)

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks mate for your feedback.Just read the code and you would understand.

Answer (score 0):

The expected is 4 and not 5. The reason why this happens is described thoroughly [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties):

> When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a
>   valid array index and that index is outside the current bounds of the
>   array, the engine will update the array's length property accordingly

Answer (score 0):

An array's `.length` will only ever count *numeric keys*. Although `box["myitem"] = "cat";` will indeed add a property named `myitem` to the `box` array, the key is not numeric, so although it'll be displayed while iterating over property names with `in`, it won't be included in the `length`.

You've only called `.push` 4 times, so the result is a `length` of only 4.

If you had assigned to a numeric property instead of `myitem` (for example, if you assigned to the property `4`), you would indeed see a change in the length.

Comment: So there's no method that get return the number of items from such array ?

Comment: If you want to get a list of *all* (enumerable) keys, you can use `Object.keys(box).length`

Answer (score 0):

`box["myitem"] = "cat";` is setting up a property on `box`. Using `length` you can get the numeric keys

```js
var box = [];
box.push({
  "cat": "kitten"
})
box.push("a string");
box.push(111); //comment 
var boxObject = {}
boxObject["material"] = "cardboard";
boxObject["dimensions"] = {
  "height": 2,
  "width": 60
} //comment
boxObject["array property Inside object"] = ["U2", "REM"];
boxObject.area = function() {
  return box.dimensions.height * box.dimensions.width;
}

box.push(boxObject); //comment
box["myitem"] = "cat";
console.log(box)
console.log(`size of array is ${box.length}`);
for (var item in box) {
  console.log(`type:${typeof box[item]} and value:`,
    box[item]);
}
console.log(`size of array is ${box.length}`);
for (var item2 in box) { // prints 5 properties
  console.log(item2)
}
```